# why doesn't java have deterministic destructors?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I don't understand why you can't have stack objects without changing syntax. If anyone makes a reference to an object that doesn't go out of scope, flag the object for GC and don't destruct it. If this isn't the case, its perfectly reasonable to destruct it.

Is it because then the class itself behaves differently whether or not the object has references? Seems solvable -- if object has a destructor, its a runtime error for an instance to go out of scope if there are external references.

Please help me understand.

Comment: meta: deterministic destruction would allow me to use RAII patterns

Comment: Boy you picked a wrong language ... :)

Comment: For now.  Java is on it's way to addressing the RAII problem.  :-)

Comment: escape analysis does that for you, you dont need to flag anything, JVM can allocate objects on the stack alike if they feel so.

Comment: bestess i would love to see an answer elaborating ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the answer as far as I can grasp is that implementing stack objects is feasible in this manner, but requires a reference counting garbage collector. Java (and presumably .NET) have avoided this route because:

> You can augment refcounting with a
>   "real" GC, which naturally has to run
>   less often because only some (often
>   small) part of the garbage generated
>   contains cycles. Another factor is
>   speed - a clever, optimized GC can do
>   much better than refcounting, in
>   particular in the presence of threads
>   (which make incrementing/decrementing
>   the refcounts much more costy, due to
>   locking)

See [this answer to why-dont-most-jvm-gcs-use-refcounts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4891133/why-dont-most-jvm-gcs-use-refcounts)

Answer (score 1):

The usual JVM implementation doesn't use reference counting; therefore, any scheme that relies on reference counting would fail on the typical JVM. It would be conforming to add reference counting to the JVM, however, such an implementation would likely be much slower.

It's not clear to me what approach you suggest in your posting. If you want somehow detect that a reference is made to an object, most likely, even the most trivial object usages would break your detection, e.g.

```
{
 A a = new A();
 a.m();
}
```

This has two problematic issues:

- Reading the local variable a already makes a reference to the object (on the evaluation stack). If "making a reference" is already considered as "not eligible as a stack object", then the approach of stack objects would be impractical
- A method is called on the object, which, in turn, might make a reference to `this` inside, invisible to the caller. So even if you have a policy that somehow allows access to local variables containing stack objects, you can't really allow method calls for stack objects. As that would include the call to `finalize()`, having stack object would be fairly pointless.

Comment: your first bullet i don't think is a barrier, given reference counting. your second bullet i don't fully understand.

Comment: if an object has finalized overriden it gets enqueued by the VM prior to executing the constructor <init> (i.e. technically you can consider it extra an reference :D )

Comment: @Dustin Getz: neither is an issue if there is reference counting, but there isn't any such thing in Java.

Comment: @bestsss: Yes, finalizers mess up the semantics of stack objects. However, the reference from the GC wouldn't cause problems unless the object resurrects itself.

Answer (score 0):

> why you can't have stack objects without changing syntax.  If anyone makes a reference to an
>   object that doesn't go out of scope,
>   flag the object for GC and don't
>   destruct it.

Except the object is *on the stack*, taking up space that you might need for your very next method call.

Comment: i dont understand why this matters? JVM could implement this with the object still on the heap and a pointer on the stack, and when the pointer goes out of scope, and the object has a destructor, check the object's refcount to make sure its not a runtime error

Comment: @Dustin: except there is no refcount.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest answer is because GC isn't run at every object deletion - it's run periodically - and it's why there's effort now behind the try-with-resources additions to JDK 7.

http://blogs.oracle.com/darcy/entry/project_coin_try_out_try

C++ gets around this issue for RAII, even with GC frameworks, by having a separate notion of stack-created objects.

Comment: i dont think the approach i proposed needs the gc to run at object deletion

Comment: "if anyone makes a reference to an object that doesn't go out of scope?"  By this do you mean any object that isn't passed as an argument?  You make a compelling argument then...

Comment: it could be passed around too, so long as nobody saves off their own references. (better lingo: saves copies of the passed reference?)

Answer (score 0):

I think this requirement would be problematic:

> if object has a destructor, its a runtime error for an instance to go out of scope if there are external references.

because it means you would need to do a GC cycle on return from any method that declared a local variable whose type has a destructor.

What might work is something similar to Eiffel's [expanded variables](http://smarteiffel.loria.fr/wiki/en/index.php/Expanded_or_reference).  It is illegal to assign to a reference variable (including a method parameter) from an expanded variable, so this problem cannot occur.