# why don't most JVM gcs use refcounts?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

Why don't they need them, and if someone decided to implement a VM that used them, what problems might they face?

Comment: b/c ref count is slower than copy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Counting references must be done outside the object.

   Counting references is slow. Even slower to deal w/ cyclic references but that's not impossible. Still slow.

   Counting references is actually very slow since it must use CAS + loop

   Not-Counting references is easier to implement and it's faster, esp. with some OS memory page tricks.

   Reference counting can be removed altogether by escape analysis, provided the object doesn't escape.

Answer (score 13):

Reference counting is subject to memory leaks due to cyclical references.  Imagine you have a simple "node" object which has a reference to another node, and suppose you set its reference to itself.  The reference count for that object will always be 1 even if there is no handle to it from a global or stack variable so it will never be garbage collected and is leaked memory.  This is a trivial example but any cyclical reference will have the same problem.

Of course, cyclical references can be detected but presumably the overhead of doing so adds enough complexity that other GC methods are more attractive.

Comment: You can augment refcounting with a "real" GC, which naturally has to run less often because only some (often small) part of the garbage generated contains cycles. Another factor is speed - a clever, optimized GC can do much better than refcounting, in particular in the presence of threads (which make incrementing/decrementing the refcounts much more costy, due to locking)

Comment: delnan, post your comment as an answer and i will select it as the answer

Comment: @delnan Not just more costly, Java threads make refcounting practically impossible. Since every thread is free to keep copies of objects in its own memory area, and writing them back to the main area at their leisure, refcounts would quickly become inconsistent.

Comment: @biziclop, sure you can publish the object as you want and keep ref. count but using CAS/loop for ref. counting would be just dumb. So overall ref.counting in a multhi-threaded environment is just a punishment to use.